# Why can't I use "return" in lambda function in python?

Tags: python, lambda

This does not work:

```
print((lambda :  return None)())
```

But this does:

```
print((lambda :  None)())
```

Why?

Comment: Why would you want to?  Do you have a specific example we can help with?

Comment: I m trying to give an educational example of the most simplistic lambda function - empty lambda

Answer (score 39):

Because `return` is a statement. Lambdas [can only contain expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

Comment: great, also insightful into the nature of lambdas - they can only contain expressions

Answer (score 13):

`lambda` functions automatically return an expression. They cannot contain statements. `return None` is a statement and therefore cannot work. `None` is an expression and therefore works.

Answer (score 10):

Lambda can execute only [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) and return result of the executed statement, return is the [**statement**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).

Consider using `or` and `and` operators to short-circuit the result for more flexibility in the values which will be returned by your lambda. See some samples below:

```
# return result of function f if bool(f(x)) == True otherwise return g(x)
lambda x: f(x) or g(x) 

# return result of function g if bool(f(x)) == True otherwise return f(x).
lambda x: f(x) and g(x)
```

Answer (score 4):

because lambda takes a number of parameters and an expression combining these parameters, and creates a small function that returns the value of the expression.

see: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html?highlight=lambda#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression

Answer (score 0):

Remember a `lambda` can call another function which can in turn `return` anything (Even another `lambda`)

```
# Does what you are asking... but not very useful
return_none_lambda = lambda : return_none()
def return_none():
    return None

# A more useful example that can return other lambdas to create multipier   functions
multiply_by = lambda x : create_multiplier_lambda(x)
def create_multiplier_lambda(x):
    return lambda y : x * y

a = multiply_by(4)
b = multiply_by(29)

print(a(2)) # prints 8
print(b(2)) # prints 58
```