# How is this Python function read?

Tags: python, numpy

Wikipedia has the following example code for [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function).

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> z = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
>>> softmax = lambda x : np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))
>>> softmax(z)
array([0.02364054, 0.06426166, 0.1746813 , 0.474833  , 0.02364054 , 0.06426166, 0.1746813 ])
```

When I run it, it runs successfully. I don't understand how to read the `lambda` function. In particular, how can the parameter `x` refer to an array element in the numerator and span all the elements in the denominator?

[Note: [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) this question presumably duplicates is about `lambdas` in general. This question is not necessarily about `lambda`. It is about how to read the `np` conventions. The answers by @Paul Panzer and @Mihai Alexandru-Ionut both answer my question. Too bad I can't check both simultaneously as answering the question.

To confirm that I understand their answers (and to clarify what my question was about):

- `x` is the entire array (as it should be since the array is passed as the argument).
- `np.exp(x)` returns the array with each element `x[i]` replaced by `np.exp(x[i])`. Call that new array `x_new`.
- `x_new/np.sum(x_new)` divides each element of `x_new` by the sum of `x_new`.

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three remarks.

The use of `lambda` in the example is actually bad style, cf. this paragraph from the [Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that
>   binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.
>
> Yes:
>
> def f(x): return 2*x
>
> No:
>
> f = lambda x: 2*x
>
> The first form means that the name of the resulting function object is
>   specifically 'f' instead of the generic ''. This is more
>   useful for tracebacks and string representations in general. The use
>   of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda
>   expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can
>   be embedded inside a larger expression)

Re the content. What you are seeing is array arithmetic. `np.exp` is a numpy `ufunc` it operates element-wise, so it will return an array of the same shape as its argument. `np.sum` is a reducing function, when called with an array as its sole argument it will return a scalar. The `/` operator is overloaded with a binary `ufunc`; like `np.exp` it operates element-wise. In addition, it does broadcasting: In this case the scalar denominator will be paired with every element of the array numerator resulting in an array.

And finally: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425683/7207392) is how to implement the softmax [properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42606665/7207392).

Comment: When I use `def` to define the funciton: `def fsoftmax(x): np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))` and then `print(fsoftmax(z))` I get `None` instead of the vector. Why is that?

Comment: @RussAbbott, you have to use `return` statement : `def fsoftmax(x): return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))`

Comment: Because a standard function have to return a result, using a return statement `return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))`. A lambda doesn't need a return statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024343/why-cant-i-use-return-in-lambda-function-in-python

Comment: OK. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression is like an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). In this context, the line

```
softmax = lambda x : np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))
```

is equivalent to

```
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))
```

Comment: See my comment on @Paul Panzer 's answer.

Comment: Please read my answer, if your function does not have a return statement, you get None as result...

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how to read the lambda function.

A lambda function is an anonymous function that is not bound to a name

> In particular, how can the parameter x refer to an array element in
>   the numerator and span all the elements in the denominator?

No, parameter `x` does not refer to an array element, but to the whole array. `np.exp(x)` method also returns a new array.

By writing  `np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))` the array resulted from `np.exp(x)` will be divided to the `sum` and it means that every item from the array will be divided to that sum.

Comment: See my comment on @Paul Panzer 's answer.